# Javascript automatic hide/show div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to automatically hide  divs in JavaScript using the below code, such that they can only be displayed/hidden upon clicking a select option:

```
//hiding the divs
$(document).ready(function(){
   function hide(){
      $(".atm").hide();
      $(".bank").hide();
   }
   hide();
});
```

For reasons unknown to me, the code does not work(the divs are still not hidden). Below is the rest of the code (it works properly, only the code above isn't hidding divs)

```
//here's my html code for div
<div class="atm">ATM</div>
<div class="bank">Bank</div>

//here's my select code
<select name="type" id="document-type" onchange="showOptions(this)">
    <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
    <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
</select>

//and here's my javascript code for displaying the hidden divs
function showOptions(s) {
    var val = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    if(val === "ATM"){
        hide();
        $(".atm").slideDown(400);
    }else
    if(val === "Bank"){
        hide();
        $(".bank").slideDown(400);
    }
};
```

Anywhere I'm going/doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML. Have you included jquery.js in the page? Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Show the HTML and obvious question did you add the reference to the library?

Comment: where is the select and where is the change event ?

Comment: Do your html div's have class="atm" & class="bank" ?

Comment: Please check my answer below, you seem to have left out hide code...

Comment: Is jQuery loading on your page? Your hide function on the top works totally fine - see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/on4zxavo/

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".atm").hide();
          $(".bank").hide();
          $('select').on('change',function(){
                if($('select').val()=='atm'){
                  $('.atm').show();
                  $('.bank').hide();
                }
                else if($('select').val()=='bank'){
                  $('.bank').show();
                  $('.atm').hide();
                }
            });
});
```

```html
<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
  <body>
<select><option value="atm">ATM</option><option value="bank">Bank</option></select>
<div class="atm">ATM</div>
<div class="bank">BANK</div>
```

Comment: Why would your code work if the OP's didn't? Why would their code not work as is?

Comment: sorry. OP's ? what did you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, **O**riginal **P**oster, the person who asked the question.

Comment: @nnnnnn Now changed. Test it please

Answer (score 0):

Bind a change event to your select

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
       function hide(){
          $(".atm").toggle();
          $(".bank").toggle();
       }
       $('select').on('change',hide).trigger('change');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="atm">atm</div>
<div class="bank">bank</div>
<select>
<option>select</option>
  <option>select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to unresolved question -
Copy the following code into a text.html file and run it a browser and let us know the result:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function hide()
{
  $('.atm').hide();
  $('.bank').hide();
}


//and here's my javascript code for displaying the hidden divs
function showOptions(s) {
    var val = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    if(val === "ATM"){
        hide();
        $(".atm").slideDown(400);
    }else
    if(val === "Bank"){
        hide();
        $(".bank").slideDown(400);
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
//here's my html code for div
<div class="atm">ATM</div>
<div class="bank">Bank</div>

//here's my select code
<select name="type" id="document-type" onchange="showOptions(this)">
    <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
    <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see update at end according to question's update:

The js looks fine to me it works in example below - may be your html:

(Do your div's in html have class='atm' & class='bank' ?)

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  function hide ()
  {
    $(".atm") .hide();
    $(".bank").hide();
    $('.btnHideShow').text('Show');
  }
  function show ()
  {
    $(".atm") .show();
    $(".bank").show();
    $('.btnHideShow').text('Hide');
  }
  $('.btnHideShow').click(function ()
  {
    if($('.atm').is(':hidden'))
    {
      show();
    }
    else
    {
      hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atm'>Div ATM</div>
<div class='bank'>Div Bank</div>
<button class="btnHideShow">Hide</button>
```

Using select:

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  function hide ()
  {
    $(".atm") .hide();
    $(".bank").hide();
    $('.btnHideShow').text('Show');
  }
  function show ()
  {
    $(".atm") .show();
    $(".bank").show();
    $('.btnHideShow').text('Hide');
  }
  $('.sel').change(function ()
  {
    //console.log($(this).val());
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === 'None')
    {
      hide();
    }
    else
    if(val === 'Bank-ATM')
    {
      show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atm'>Div ATM</div>
<div class='bank'>Div Bank</div>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Bank-ATM</option>
  <option>None</option>
</select>
```

In your update to the question you left out your hide function:
(are you including jquery lib?)

```js
function hide()
{
  $('.atm').hide();
  $('.bank').hide();
}


//and here's my javascript code for displaying the hidden divs
function showOptions(s) {
    var val = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    if(val === "ATM"){
        hide();
        $(".atm").slideDown(400);
    }else
    if(val === "Bank"){
        hide();
        $(".bank").slideDown(400);
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//here's my html code for div
<div class="atm">ATM</div>
<div class="bank">Bank</div>

//here's my select code
<select name="type" id="document-type" onchange="showOptions(this)">
    <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
    <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i have included the jquery library, and the hide() function is still in place

Comment: it becoming frastrating

Comment: please copy the code at the top of my answer into a text.html and tell me if it runs in your browser (hopefully Chrome)...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".atm").hide();
    $(".bank").hide();
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(".atm").toggle();
        $(".bank").toggle();
    }).
});
```

Try this. This will hide the classess on page load and then after changing the select box it will show. toggle() function is used to hide and show the elements.